# How to increment an attribute so that its value is (at least) 1 higher than the other records and unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Payment` model with an attribute `invoice_nr`. This attribute should increment (by 1) before it's saved. It's important that all `payments` have a unique `invoice_nr`.

I could use a `before_save` callback that increments `invoice_nr` by 1 relative to `Payment.maximum("invoice_nr")`:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :increment_invoice_nr

  private
    def increment_invoice_nr
      self.invoice_nr = Payment.maximum("invoice_nr") + 1
    end
end
```

But I think this doesn't ensure the uniqueness of `invoice_nr`. If two `payments` get saved at the same time they theoretically could get the same `invoice_nr`...right?

It's okay if there are gaps in between `invoice_nrs`, but you'll get bonus points if you know a way to prevent this :)

**EDIT**

Some folks suggest using the auto increment feature that most databases have. This works but it would tie my app to the specific database I'm using. Therefore the auto increment logic belongs in the app imo.

Comment: You should take a dive into transactions, just google for rails transactions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a database sequence.

migration:

```
  def up
    execute 'CREATE SEQUENCE tr_num_seq START 10000000;'
  end
```

model:

```
class model < ActiveRecord:Base
  after_initialize :set_omd_id
  def set_unique_number
        if self.tr_number.nil?
      self.tr_number = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value("select nextval('tr_number_seq')")
    end
  end
end
```

Everytime a model object is created, it will set a unqiue "invoice number id" if it is not already set

Comment: This only works for sql databases right? What does the 10000000 mean?

Comment: The sequence starts with 1 million as the first value. I am not sure about other databases, but there should be an equivalent of sequence.

Comment: Please see my edit: I think the auto increment logic should be in the app and not in the database since it will tie my app to the specific database I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a primary key with auto increment following should work

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :increment_invoice_nr

  private
    def increment_invoice_nr
      some_high_integer = 10000000
      self.update_attribute('invoice_nr', self.id + some_high_integer)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the auto increment feature from the RDBMS of your choice. Using it you wouldn't have to do it yourself and it'd be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a unique validation in your model.That will prevent it save duplicate values.
In your payment method add the following:

```
validates :invoice_nr, :uniqueness => true
```

You can also use `auto increment` if you are using mysql or other RDBMS

Comment: This only prevents the record from being saved if `invoice_nr` isn't unique. Is there a way to ensure uniqueness so that it always validates?

Comment: yes the logic is you will have some nil values in your invoice_nr.But if will never insert any duplicate value.Then after sometime you can make a gap with the current maximum and insert those values(with nil in the databse) may be using a rake task.So to me this is the solution.And i dont think you will face this situation often because you are talking about milliseconds and its near impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
def increment_invoice_nr
  invoice_nr_arr = Payment.all.map(&:invoice_nr)
  invoice = Payment.maximum("invoice_nr") 
  until invoice_nr_arr.include?(invoice) == false
    invoice += 1
  end
  self.invoice_nr = invoice
end
```

This method will first collect all invoice_nr. Then it will check the incremented invoice_nr includes/exists in your payments table or not. If it exists then it will go on incrementing the invoice_nr by 1 till it gets the unique invoice_nr.

Comment: This won't solve the potential race condition. At the moment you save the record the same invoice_nr could be used for another record. Your `until` block basically does the same as the `maximum` method. I think I need a transaction...

Comment: Oh!! You just want that your invoice_nr should be unique value. Right? Then you can use after_save callback. In after_save callback, update your invoice_nr by the id of your record. Id is always unique.